# Git error - pathspec 'test' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git

I just create new git repository:

```
git init
```

and I've got response

```
Initialized empty Git repository in E:/...
```

Then I try to create new branch:

```
git checkout test
```

and got an error:

```
pathspec 'test' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I have no remote repository, no commits, and no idea what is wrong.

Comment: git branch test, would create a new branch.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the branch first. `git checkout -b test` would create the branch and switch to it, or `git branch test` to just create it but not switch to the branch.

After doing this you will be able to switch to the branch via `git checkout test` as you are doing, but on its own it won't create the new branch.

This page would be informative for you: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging